# Python OpenCV identify crop rows

Tags: python, opencv

I am new to OpenCV. Referring various forums and articles, I was able to come up with the following script. Attached the output of the script.

I am trying to identify all major lines to separate the sky, crop and the trench. But with the code I was able to identify only 1 line.

```
#!./.venv/bin/python3

import cv2 as cv
import sys
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

image = cv.imread(cv.samples.findFile("images/1.jpeg"))
if image is None:
    sys.exit("Could not read the image.")

hsv = cv.cvtColor(image, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

mask = cv.inRange(hsv, (36, 25, 25), (70, 255, 255))
#mask = cv.inRange(hsv, (15, 255, 150), (92, 255, 150))

imask = mask>0
green = np.zeros_like(image, np.uint8)
green[imask] = image[imask]
cv.imshow("green", green)

gray = cv.cvtColor(green, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv.imshow("gray", gray)

blur = cv.GaussianBlur(gray, (11, 11), 0)
cv.imshow("blur", blur)

canny_image = cv.Canny(blur, 50, 200, None, 3)
cv.imshow("canny_image", canny_image)

"""
plt.subplot(121),plt.imshow(canny_image)  #,cmap = 'gray'
plt.title('Original Image'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(122),plt.imshow(green)
plt.title('Edge Image'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])

plt.show()
"""

# Copy edges to the images that will display the results in BGR
cdst = cv.cvtColor(canny_image, cv.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
cdstP = np.copy(cdst)

lines = cv.HoughLines(canny_image, 1, np.pi / 180, 150, None, 0, 0)

if lines is not None:
    for i in range(0, len(lines)):
        rho = lines[i][0][0]
        theta = lines[i][0][1]
        a = math.cos(theta)
        b = math.sin(theta)
        x0 = a * rho
        y0 = b * rho
        pt1 = (int(x0 + 1000*(-b)), int(y0 + 1000*(a)))
        pt2 = (int(x0 - 1000*(-b)), int(y0 - 1000*(a)))
        cv.line(cdst, pt1, pt2, (0,0,255), 3, cv.LINE_AA)

linesP = cv.HoughLinesP(canny_image, 1, np.pi / 180, 50, None, 50, 10)

if linesP is not None:
    for i in range(0, len(linesP)):
        l = linesP[i][0]
        cv.line(cdstP, (l[0], l[1]), (l[2], l[3]), (0,0,255), 3, cv.LINE_AA)

cv.imshow("Source", image)
cv.imshow("Detected Lines (in red) - Standard Hough Line Transform", cdst)
cv.imshow("Detected Lines (in red) - Probabilistic Line Transform", cdstP)

cv.waitKey()
```

[image: output screenshot]

Comment: Please let me know if I am on looking at it wrong.

Comment: Why houghline? Segmentation seems better for this pproblem

Comment: Hi @YunusTemurlenk, This is what I was able to understand in 7 hours right from how to install opencv. So I could very well be on the wrong track. On one forum they had used houghline to identify road, which is quite close to what I am trying to do, hence i used the same. Will check out segmentation.

http://www.robindavid.fr/opencv-tutorial/chapter5-line-edge-and-contours-detection.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it working with OpenCV inbuilt function's maxLineGap parameter

```
#!./.venv/bin/python3

import cv2 as cv
import sys
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

image = cv.imread(cv.samples.findFile("images/1.jpeg"))
if image is None:
    sys.exit("Could not read the image.")

hsv = cv.cvtColor(image, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

mask = cv.inRange(hsv, (36, 25, 25), (70, 255, 255))
#mask = cv.inRange(hsv, (15, 255, 150), (92, 255, 150))

imask = mask>0
green = np.zeros_like(image, np.uint8)
green[imask] = image[imask]
cv.imshow("green", green)

gray = cv.cvtColor(green, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv.imshow("gray", gray)

blur = cv.GaussianBlur(gray, (11, 11), 0)
cv.imshow("blur", blur)

canny_image = cv.Canny(blur, 50, 200, None, 3)
cv.imshow("canny_image", canny_image)

lines = cv.HoughLinesP(canny_image, 1, np.pi/100, 30, maxLineGap=18)
for line in lines:
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = line[0]
    cv.line(image, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 0, 255), 3)

cv.imshow("final", image)

cv.waitKey()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: final edges]

Answer (score 1):

```
**This is what I tried, here you can filter the lines**

    #!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Mon Jun  8 16:17:31 2020

@author: hariprasad
"""

import cv2 as cv
import sys
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math



image = cv.imread(cv.samples.findFile("crop.jpeg"))
image = cv.resize(image,(500,500))
if image is None:
    sys.exit("Could not read the image.")

hsv = cv.cvtColor(image, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

mask = cv.inRange(hsv, (36, 25, 25), (70, 255, 255))
#mask = cv.inRange(hsv, (15, 255, 150), (92, 255, 150))

imask = mask>0
green = np.zeros_like(image, np.uint8)
green[imask] = image[imask]
cv.imshow("green", green)

gray = cv.cvtColor(green, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
#cv.imshow("gray", gray)

blur = cv.GaussianBlur(gray, (11, 11), 0)


_,thresh = cv.threshold(gray,127,255,cv.THRESH_BINARY)
#cv.imshow("thresh",thresh)
kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
closing = cv.morphologyEx(thresh, cv.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
dilation = cv.dilate(closing,kernel,iterations = 3)
#cv.imshow("dilate",dilation)
blur = cv.GaussianBlur(dilation, (11, 11), 0)
#cv.imshow("blur", blur)
canny_image = cv.Canny(blur, 50, 200, None, 3)
#cv.imshow("canny_image", canny_image)










def dist(x, y, x1, y1):
    return ((x-x1)**2+(y-y1)**2)**(0.5)


def slope(x, y, x1, y1):
    if y1 != y:
        return ((x1-x)/(y1-y))
    else:
        return 0

fld = cv.ximgproc.createFastLineDetector()
lines = fld.detect(canny_image)
result_img = fld.drawSegments(canny_image, lines)
for line in lines:
    x0 = int(round(line[0][0]))
    y0 = int(round(line[0][1]))
    x1 = int(round(line[0][2]))
    y1 = int(round(line[0][3]))
    cv.line(canny_image, (x0, y0), (x1, y1), 255, 1, cv.LINE_AA)
    #dlist = []
    d = dist(x0, y0, x1, y1)
    #dlist.append(d)

    if d :
        #cv.line(image, (x0, y0), (x1, y1), (0, 255, 0), 2, cv.LINE_AA)

        m = (slope(x0, y0, x1, y1))
        print(m)

        if m>=2 :#and m!=0:# and m < 2:
            cv.line(image, (x0, y0), (x1, y1), (255, 0, 255), 2, cv.LINE_AA)
        elif m> -3 and m<0.5: 
            cv.line(image, (x0, y0), (x1, y1), (255, 255, 0), 1, cv.LINE_AA)


cv.imshow("Source", result_img)
cv.imshow("Source1", image)
cv.imwrite("op.jpeg",image)
#cv.imshow("Detected Lines (in red) - Standard Hough Line Transform", cast)
#cv.imshow("Detected Lines (in red) - Probabilistic Line Transform", cdstP)

cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: output image]

Comment: Thanks Hariprasad. Those are some really good pointers that would help me learning in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the output similar to the output shown in the image.

[image: output image, I have tried with your code]

Comment: Hi Hariprasad, somewhat similar, but at single row level. I am trying to build a bot which will travel through each row and measure moisture level at particular intervals.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/9267284/hariprasad Can you please let know how you achieved the above? Thanks

Comment: Here I have used Fast LIne detection and also done a few morphological operations like closing and dilation, can you please post your input image I will check once and post code...

Comment: Hi Hariprasad, Its present in the screenshot in the question. Do you mean original image?

Comment: I can't seem to find how to upload image here. But it was something I downloaded from internet https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcTt1inDSzP1y5a_jdmDw3qCk6Q2WRf9Fxx7q-TfQmNzcBoY7j7V&usqp=CAU

Thanks